# extract all jar dependency from maven based project and add them to tomcat lib

Tags: maven, tomcat

I have a maven based project and my war file would be bigger than 100M. because of firewalls and some network policies in our company, it takes hours to transfer my new war file to our server. 
I want to exclude all jar dependencies and locate them into Tomcat lib. How can I handle it in maven? and how can I add my dependencies to tomcat classpath? thank you

Comment: How often do you need to deploy?  Could this be done when time is less of an issue, e.g. overnight?

Comment: it depend's on our customer's orders. sometimes we have to deploy  as soon as posible

Answer (score 0):

- You can utilize the maven dependency plugin in order to collect the dependencies in a folder: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html
- If you place the libraries in the lib folder of the tomcats they are available for the tomcat common/shared classloader. If you want to put them in a subfolder to avoid mixing up with already present jars used by tomcat you can add that in catalina.properties.
- If you have to deplyoy several webapps on the tomcat with possibly different versions of the same dependency you could run in very ugly problems because the loading of the libs by the common classloader is more or less "random".